# Elegantly handling base class dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

In the project I'm working on, I've added a base ViewModel class which contains some functionality and dependencies common to all ViewModels. It provides validation, messaging, dispatching and navigation services through the following properties:

```
IValidateProperties Validator { get; }
IMessenger Messenger { get; }
IDispatcherHelper DispatcherHelper { get; }
INavigationService Navigation { get; }
```

I use an IoC container to wire my dependencies, however I have a few options for how to handle these dependencies which are common to all of my ViewModels:

1. Inject them in the constructor. If I did this, then it would require adding these four arguments to the constructor of every single ViewModel and pass them to the base constructor. That's a lot of extra noise added to my code base, which I'd really rather avoid. Also, if I were to add another dependency at some point, that would require changing the constructor of every single ViewModel.
2. Use property injection. This is the approach I'm working with now. Unfortunately, it means not being able to access these properties until after the ViewModel has been constructed, resulting in the following workarounds:

   ```
   private IValidateProperties _validator;
   public IValidateProperties Validator
   {
       get => _validator;
       set
       {
           _validator = value;
           _validator.ValidationTarget = this;
       }
   }

   private IMessenger _messenger;
   public IMessenger Messenger
   {
       get => _messenger;
       set
       {
           _messenger = value;
           MessengerAttached();
       }
   }

   protected virtual void MessengerAttached() { }
   ```
3. Make the properties static and inject them on app startup. This is easy for `Messenger`, `DispatcherHelper` and `Navigation` because they are used as singletons anyway. For `Validator`, I would need to add a static `ValidatorFactory`, and instantiate the `Validator` in the constructor using the factory. This way seems to be the cleanest way to do things, but I have this voice in the back of my head telling me that using statics like this is a bad idea.

I feel like option 1 is out of the question because of the large amount of noisy boilerplate code it would result in being added to my ViewModels. I'm still unsure whether 2 or 3 is the best way to go though. Is there a good reason that using statics is a bad idea in this case, or am I fretting over nothing?

Some people argue that statics lead to untestable code, but in this case it would actually make things easier to test. If I were to go with option 3, I could add the following class for all of my view model tests to inherit:

```
public abstract class ViewModelTestBase
{
    protected readonly IValidateProperties ValidatorMock;
    protected readonly IMessenger MessengerMock;
    protected readonly IDispatcherHelper DispatcherHelperMock;
    protected readonly INavigationService NavigationMock;

    protected ViewModelTestBase()
    {
        ValidatorMock = Substitute.For<IValidateProperties>();
        ViewModelBase.Validator = ValidatorMock;

        MessengerMock = Substitute.For<IMessenger>();
        ViewModelBase.Messenger = MessengerMock;

        DispatcherHelperMock = Substitute.For<IDispatcherHelper>();
        ViewModelBase.DispatcherHelper = DispatcherHelperMock;

        NavigationMock = Substitute.For<INavigationService>();
        ViewModelBase.Navigation = NavigationMock;
    }
}
```

So, what concrete reasons are there for not going with approach #3? And if statics really are such a bad idea in this case, what concrete reasons are there for not going with approach #2 instead?

Comment: Very opinion based question... Here is mine 1,2,3: go with 1 as this is approach commonly expected from code using IOC. Likely no one would expect static properties set by IOC for 3,  and with 2 while it is reasonable it feels you already have some issues with timing of the call for your particular usage case (possibly trying to use those properties in the constructor) ...

Comment: The IoC container I am using does property injection, so it works with option 2. Option 3 means I have to manually set their values once on app start instead of using the IoC container, but honestly I'm not too stuffed about that since I only have to do it once. I'm wondering if there actually are any specific reasons not to go with option 3.

Comment: I'd expect question to be other way around - what would be strong reason to use static... Presumably you are writing WPF code without any tests and never going to use multithreading or shift to writing ASP.Net (or other code that may handle more than one request in parallel) - you may have good reasons to stick with static... You may want to read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161222/dont-use-static-in-c or some other search results for https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+should+i+use+static

Comment: I recommend #1.  Using statics makes your code not easily testable, which goes against one of the main reasons to use dependency injection.  Yes, it'll be some extra boilerplate code, but it's easy code to write.  You could create a facade service like `ViewModelManager` which encapsulates all of those common dependencies so that you only have to deal with one extra parameter to your view model constructors.  That would also prevent you from having to add extra parameters to your view model constructors if you make another dependency later.

Comment: #1 is my recomendation, too. See: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/ for the explanation and details. That works also for future changes and enhancements with minimal effort.

Comment: I do have unit tests, and using statics in this case wouldn't make the code any less testable. I would still be able to mock these dependencies and inject the mocks in my tests if I used statics. In fact statics would actually make this easier to do since then I could also have a base viewmodel test class which sets up these mocks in its constructor. Right now I'm injecting them in my tests only when needed.

Comment: Statics do make code less testable because they create an ambient context of dependencies, which you'll need to configure during your tests.  A good unit test should be completely self contained and shouldn't rely on any extra configuration of a set of global static variables.  The configuration may seem obvious to you now, but think about it from the perspective of another programmer who's writing tests for your code, or think about yourself returning to this project after a few years of absence. Using statics for dependencies is pretty widely regarded as a bad idea.

Comment: @BenRubin if I have a `ViewModelTestBase ` class which all of my viewmodel tests inherit, and which instantiates mocks for these four dependencies and injects them into my base viewmodel class, how is this problematic? Any future programmer can jump into the base test class to see the dependencies being mocked and injected there. That voice in the back of my head agrees that statics are a bad idea, but I'm really looking for concrete reasons why.

Comment: @KBO the main issue I have with this is that those four dependencies aren't really related in any way that would allow me to add a layer of abstraction on top of them, so any "aggregate service" class I make for them would effectively just be a container for them and would do nothing but forward calls to them, which sems a bit smelly to me. Also, this would reduce all the boilerplate and make it more maintainable, but doesn't eliminate it completely as the other options do, and still results in some noise.

Comment: @Katie What do you mean your tests inherit `ViewModelTestBase`?

Comment: @BenRubin I've updated the question with an example

Comment: @Katie Yes, your example works and cuts down on the amount of code you have to write, but you're straying into the land of the service locator anti pattern.  Using dependency injection, your classes should not create their own dependencies.  Even though your view model classes aren't creating dependencies directly, their base class looks to be creating its own dependencies, so your derived view model classes are essentially creating their own dependencies too (to be continued)

Comment: @BenRubin My base viewmodel class is not creating its own dependencies. They are injected by my IoC container using property injection. If I switched to #3, then they would be injected once on app startup

Comment: Having external configuration (as in the case of having dependencies created in a base class) makes code less testable because it would not be immediately clear from looking at the code what's going on.  You'd have to have prior knowledge of how your static configuration works in order to understand where those dependencies are coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160106/discussion-between-ben-rubin-and-katie).